# Show download speeds in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, data-transfer

When downloading files in Safari you can see your current downloads in `View -> Current Downloads` or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>

[image]

If my memory serves me right, this window also showed the download speeds as well (this was in previous versions of Safari when it used to be a separate window). But I can not figure out how to bring up the downloads speeds.

My question: How can I see my current download speeds in Safari (version 6) without the use of any extensions of third party apps?

Comment: Safari Version 8.0 (10538.46) in OS X Mavericks beta does not have this 'feature' and always shows the download speed, as expected :)

Answer (score 4):

After reading this [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4151103) and with the reproducibility described here, I started to believe that **this is a bug**. In this thread OS X users complain that *sometimes download speed is visible* and sometimes not.
It was suggested to **completely** quit Safari, open terminal and execute:

```
rm ~/Library/Safari/Downloads.plist
```

And launch Safari again. That **did not work** for me.

**The following steps might show your download speed** (*80% change, your mileage may vary*):

- Start a download
- Pause that download
- Close the download window
- Wait 5 seconds and open the download window
- Resuming the download
- *(after closing the download window, you need to do this all over again)*

Screenshot, showing visible download speed (OS X 10.8.5 and Safari 6.0.5):
[image]

Comment: Indeed pause and resume does the trick some times, for me it is more 10% than 80%. The download speeds sometimes show when hovering the mouse cursor over the area just below the X and the magnifying-glass, but usually it does not.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the downloads popover-window has a fixed width, and if there room for the download speed it will show it, but if there isn't enough room it won't show it. In most cases though, it will show the speed if you close the window and open it again.

Answer (score -1):

I coludn't check it, but usually in apple software there is a pattern: <kbd>Option</kbd>+Click gives you more information.

Try it on progress bar.

Comment: 'Option'+'Click' does the same as 'Click' -> nothing.

Comment: This worked for me (Option)+Click, why downrate him?

Answer (score -5):

just click twice on the download window...the second time will appear detailed ;)

cheers

Comment: This behaviour is not consistent.